# Word VBA: Findtext pattern with an optional character (Find method)

Tags: vba, pattern-matching, ms-word

I have what should be a simple question. I am searching a document for occurrences of bracketed numbers, e.g.  `[4]` or `[14]` etc. I can write a pattern to find either a single digit or a double digit, but how do I use a single `FindText` pattern that matches both cases?

Here is my working code for the single digit case:

```
set fnd=ActiveDocument.Range.Find
While (fnd.Execute(FindText:="\[[0-9]\]", MatchWildcards:=True))
    ...
    Do Stuff
    ...
Wend
```

How can I adapt this to include the possibility of a second digit? Thanks for your help!

Comment: FindText:="\[[0-9]{1,2}\]"  See #7 here - http://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub SearchNumbersInSqBrackets()

    Dim rng
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range

    With rng.Find
        .Text = "\[[0-9]{1,2}\]"
        .MatchWildcards = True

        Do While .Execute(Forward:=True)
            Debug.Print rng.Text
        Loop

    End With
End Sub
```

See #7 here - http://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm